# C++ return type qualifiers heaven

Tags: c++, visual-c++, return-type, qualifiers

It's hell actually. Can someone please explain in plain English why the below segments work or not?

```
class Hey;

class Bitmap {

public:
    const Hey* const& getHey() { return hey; }; // works
    const Hey* & getHey2() { return hey; }; // error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'Hey *' to 'const Hey *&'

private:
    Hey* hey;
};
```

Comment: What is this `Fair` you speak of?

Comment: What's wrong with returning the simple `const Hey *` - what do you need the reference for?

Comment: It looks like you have a name space issue, did you pre-declare your class inside a different namespace? And don't return reference pointers, its bad karma :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't add `const` to a pointer more than one type deep which is not itself `const`, because then you could stuff the address of a `const` variable into a non-`const` pointer.  Consider:

```
char c;
char* p = &c;
const char* cp = p; // ok, only one type deep
const char x;
cp = &x; // ok
const char*& r = p; // fail, because...
r = cp; // ok
*p = 5; // ok, would overwrite a const variable if binding r to p were allowed
```

Making the pointer `const` prevents this disaster a different way.  Continuing the example:

```
const char* const& cr = p; // ok
cr = cp; // fail, cr is const, saving us from...
*p = 5; // would overwrite a const variable if cr = cp were allowed
```

Answer (score 1):

A const reference can be initialized to an object of a different type or to an rvalue , such as a constant expression:

```
  const int i = 42;
  //  legal for const references only
  const int &r = i;
```

The same initializations are not legal for nonconst references.

You are trying to initialize reference with const expression. Const expression  is rvalue. The const reference can be initialize with rvalue, while non const can't.

**Edit**: About rvalues and lvalues you can read in [weakipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29) .

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't see "Hey*" and "const Hey*" as the same so it doesn't want to convert the reference whereas he convert the const reference (similar to parameter conversion)